# Apple Magic Mouse 2 scrolling not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, bluetooth, apple

## I'm willing to pay someone to develop a solution.

I'm using a fresh install of vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.3 with an Apple Magic Mouse 2.

The device connected via Bluetooth without issue, and recognizes left and right click out of the box.

However, it does not recognize scrolling.

I have found numerous forum posts and blog articles about this, but the solutions are either outdated or are incomplete.

I'm wondering if anyone has it working and can explain how I can get it working.

Note: hid_magicmouse / hid-magicmouse module is not available on my machine and have not been able to locate instructions on how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple's stuffs is weird, give a try to a newer (or better, the latest) version of Ubuntu (the 17.10).

This lets you to use the latest kernel, which it has a more complete hardware support.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am already running 17.10 and have also tested on 16.04 and 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

Things worth to try:

- checking if udev correctly recognizes your mouse (I mean as Magic Mouse):

  Here is a snippet of my (Ubuntu 16.04) `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/90-libinput-model-quirks.hwdb`

  ```
  # Apple
  ##########################################
  libinput:touchpad:input:b0003v05ACp*
  libinput:touchpad:input:b0005v05ACp*
   LIBINPUT_MODEL_APPLE_TOUCHPAD=1
   LIBINPUT_ATTR_SIZE_HINT=104x75

  libinput:name:*Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard*:dmi:*
   LIBINPUT_MODEL_APPLE_INTERNAL_KEYBOARD=1

  libinput:mouse:input:b0005v05ACp030D*
   LIBINPUT_MODEL_APPLE_MAGICMOUSE=1
  ```

  What if you need your Magic Mouse 2 to enable `LIBINPUT_MODEL_APPLE_MAGICMOUSE`? I do not have these devices, but as I checked Magic Mouse 1 and Magic Mouse 2 has no functional difference (from computer point of view) - maybe just the "name", like `b0005v05ACp030D`
- playing with udev hwdb data (`/etc/udev/hwdb.d`) - original files are sitting in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d`.

  I suggest to start with `sudo evtest` (choose the Magic Mouse input device) and try to scroll. You will see what udev events show up. If `evtest` gave events exclusively scroll-up/down, you can make conversion here.

  Until here no programming skills were needed.
- If nothing helped (but you got udev events) you can create "custom" event program, like I tried (changing my power button to `KEY_4` or make working my Wifi button). Source is here: [Is there a way to disable Airplane mode button on laptop keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400300/is-there-a-way-to-disable-airplane-mode-button-on-laptop-keyboard/401125#401125)

Comment: Thanks Mark. These seem like ideas I will test and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I checked my `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-mouse.hwdb` file and confirmed I have the same line you do for the Magic Mouse. There is not a second entry for the version 2 though. And I do agree it could be as simple as changing that number / ID, but I don't know how to identify what that number could be.

I also installed `evtest` for both my v1 and v2 and it recognized scroll events for 1 but not for 2.

Thank you for your help it's been insightful but I am not sure where else to go from here.

Comment: I can confirm no scroll events with the magic mouse 2 in evtest. From what I've read on the subject Apple uses a proprietary protocol for the scroll events in v2, which could explain the problem.